# Distribute S/MIME public keys and CA cert for email security

Tags: certificates, public-key-infrastructure, smime

I have my own CA. I want to distribute S/MIME certificates for 10 different users.
I saw S/MIME keyservers from http://wiki.cacert.org/KeyServers, but I don't want to use public servers. What is the best way in your opinion?

1. Deliver manually all certs as a `zip` or `p7b` file in 10 CDs to users; or
2. Create my own key server. Is there any open source solution for S/MIME keyserver?

I have the same problem for distributing CA certificate. 
Can you help me?

Comment: [Cross-post](http://superuser.com/q/860138/151741).

Comment: What communication channels do you have with the users? What is your threat model?